# Can I implement the blockchain technology to build my own app that decentralizes renewable energy in the place I live?

Tags: blockchain

Probably someone has already asked this question but I searched for quite a while and could not find a "simple" answer.
So I would like to implement the blockchain tech into my app that will regulate finances and renewable energy flow from house to house in the place that I live in.
I just want to know if this is possible.

If theres an easier way,maybe using the Ethereum platform to build my app on...?

I'm grateful for any kind of a reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible, but the blockchain technology will be just one aspect of your system. You'll also need to determine how to feed data from the distributed energy grid into the blockchain and use it to meter incentives. I think a similar concept can be achieved with wireless mesh networks to decentralize internet access.

The blockchain aspect is just the incentive layer. Figure out how to create incentives that can't easily be gamed for producing and transmitting power or packets and you're on your way. The challenge though, is preventing the incentives from being gamed.

Comment: Thank you @robrigo for the reply.By "preventing the incentives from being gamed" you mean not letting people manipulate data about the incentives and power transmittion? If yes,wouldnt the blockchain regulate that whole part of the system? Sorry for bugging you,thank you again for the time.